# image_geometry projectPixelTo3dRay World Coordinates

Tags: ros, calibration, opencv, image-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening,
i have a problem and i need help as fast as possible. For a tracking program i try to subscribe from two `image_rect_color` + their `camera_infos`. i have already calibrated the cameras with the ros package `camera_calibration` and i stored in the camera_info file. Now i am trying to get real world coordinates with the `image_geometry` package.

Put if i pick a pixel point (98,200) and compute it via  `projectPixelTo3dRay`it only gives me strange values and z is always 1.
Example: point (98,200) = [-0.269315, -0.0648566, 1]. Do i understand something wrong? What else can I do to get real world coordinates? The intrinsic and extrinsic values are stored in the `camera_info`.

Please help its important for me!

```
image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel model1;
image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel model2;

void callback(const ImageConstPtr& sub1, const CameraInfoConstPtr& cam_info1,const ImageConstPtr& sub2 , const CameraInfoConstPtr& cam_info2){


    double stamp_1 =sub1->header.stamp.toSec();
    double stamp_2 =sub2->header.stamp.toSec();
    ROS_INFO("\nCALLBACK GETS CALLED\n TIME_STAMP_IMAGE1: %f\n TIME_STAMP_IMAGE2: %f\n", stamp_1, stamp_2);
    model1.fromCameraInfo(cam_info1);
    model2.fromCameraInfo(cam_info2);
    cv::Point2d pixel_point(98, 200);
    cv::Point3d xyz = model1.projectPixelTo3dRay(pixel_point);
    cout << "point (3D) = " << xyz << endl << endl;


}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ros::init( argc, argv, "sync_test" );
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    //namedWindow("window1", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    //namedWindow("window2", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    //cv::startWindowThread();

    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> sub1(nh, "/usb_cam/image_rect_color", 5);
    message_filters::Subscriber<CameraInfo> info_sub1(nh, "/usb_cam/camera_info", 5);
    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> sub2(nh, "/usb_cam/image_rect_color", 5);
    message_filters::Subscriber<CameraInfo> info_sub2(nh, "/usb_cam/camera_info", 5);


    typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<Image,CameraInfo,Image,CameraInfo> MySyncPolicy;
    // ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)

    Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), sub1,info_sub1, sub2,info_sub2);
    //sync.setAgePenalty(1.0);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2,_3,_4));

    ros::spin();

    return 0;

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223953/image_geometry-projectpixelto3dray-world-coordinates/) by [Gren8](https://answers.ros.org/users/25538/gren8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pixel corresponds to a ray that starts at your camera position and passes through the point (-0.269315, -0.0648566, 1) (in your camera frame). If you pass the center point of your image, the point should be (0,0,1). z = 1 is just a random point on this line.

The docu is also very helpful: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html#ad52a4a71c6f6d375d69865e40a117ca3

http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/image_geometry/html/c++/pinhole__camera__model_8cpp_source.html#l00267

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gren8](https://answers.ros.org/users/25538/gren8/) on 2016-01-12**:
thanks for the answer! If i take a random point (400,56) the output is [0.102615, -0.244058, ] Could you give me an example of how i get my real world coordinates in mm now? I know its in the link you posted but i don't really understand it.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-01-12**:
The point is in m, so just multiply with 1000?

**Comment by [Gren8](https://answers.ros.org/users/25538/gren8/) on 2016-01-12**:
but if my output is a unit vector [0.102615, -0.244058, 1 ] and i multiply it by 1000 why do i get a negative mm value?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-01-12**:
why do you expect positive values for all axis?